# Stoping xml parsing when a particular element is found

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I have an xml which needs to be parsed. 
  my

```
$parser = new XML::Parser(Handlers => 
        {Init => \&handle_Init, Start => \&handle_Start,
         Char => \&handle_Char, End =>\&handle_End, 
         Final => \&handle_Final});

 $parser->parsefile("ababab.xml");
```

In the handle_Char subroutine , as soon as I find a particular tag and its value, I want to stop.

How is it possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the call to parsefile in an eval and then die in the handler. You will then need to test $@ to see if parsing succeeded

An example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Parser;

my $p = XML::Parser->new(Handlers => { End => sub { if( $_[1] eq 'e') { die "ok"; } } });

print "parsing well-formed xml: ";
eval { $p->parse( '<d><b/><e/></d>'); };
if( $@ =~ m{^ok} ) { print "success\n"; } else { print $@; }

print "parsing malformed xml: ";
eval { $p->parse( '<d<b/><e/></d>'); };
if( $@ =~ m{^ok} ) { print "success\n"; } else { print $@; }
```

That said I would not use XML::Parser. The Perl5 wiki has a [list of recommended modules](https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/index.cgi?xml) for XML parsing.

Comment: Your tests are backwards, your printing success when parsing fails.
Also if you are going to use `die` for non-fatal flow control please use exception objects. `die` accepts as it's argument objects which are then available in `$@` this allows structured tests instead of string matches. There are a number of CPAN modules to do some of the work for you or you can roll your own.

Comment: Agreed, there is *rarely* a need for explicitly using `eval` and `$@` for checking exceptions. The simplest and smallest exception handling package is currently Try::Tiny; in unit tests you can use Test::Fatal.

Comment: Oops, backwards test fixed, that's what I get for posting an answer before my morning coffee. As for the exception advice, if you have a better way, then by all means post it.